# Request mapping - Spring 4 - doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, request

I have a very simple problem. When in my .jsp files I have a link to **/registration the method viewRegistration is executed and everything is working fine. If I have a link to **/registration/getTags?tagName=blahblah page is not found. I have no idea why, because I think my requestMapping annotation looks correct... I would be very grateful for your help!

CONTROLLER:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration")
public class HelloController {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewRegistration(Map<String, Object> model, HttpSession session) {
        ...
   }

@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Tag> getTags(@RequestParam String tagName) {

        ....

    }
}
```

WEB.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>aa</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/registration/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/xxx-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

xxx-servlet.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="movies.controller" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/properties/website.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"
        id="tilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tile/tilesJsp.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
        id="viewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="website" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT:
I even tried sth more simple:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Tag> getTags() {
        String tagName="";
        return simulateSearchResult(tagName);

    }
```

but still /registration/getTags does not work..., page not found.

Comment: Please refer to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60763923/10976088

Answer (score 5):

the `servlet` url mapping is as follows :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/registration/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

which means that all `urls` that begin with `/registration/*` will be handled by the `servlet`, what comes after it , it will be handled by the `controller`.
So if you configure your controller with a `@RequestMapping(value="/otherURL")`  it will serve the following `Url` :

`http://localhost:xxxx/<appname>/registration/otherURL`

And in this case in order to access the right method you should either:

- `@RequestMapping("/registration`) from the controller, cause it is already mapped on the servlet level, and calling :

  `http://localhost:xxxx/<appname>/registration/getTags?tagName=blahblah` will work correctly.
  **OR**:
- Call this URL : `http://localhost:xxxx/<appname>/registration/registration/getTags?tagName=blahblah`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle requests to `**/registration/getTags`, change your controller method mapping to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**/registration/getTags", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your mapping should be fine. However, I believe you're running into this because you're requesting `"/registration/getTags?name=blahblah"` and yet your handler's parameter is "tagName". Try changing your request to `"/registration/getTags?tagName=blahblah"`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

Comment: No, it's not a problem. I also tried tagName(I updated my question)

Answer (score 1):

As Nick Cromwell mentioned the issue with your mapping is the mismatch between the name of the parameter in your request and in your mapping. So either change in the request as he mentions, rename the argument in the handler method, or use the `value` attribute of the *@RequestParam* annotation, e.g.

```
List<Tag> getTags(@RequestParam(value="name") String tagName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the requestParam as following:

```
List<Tag> getTags(@RequestParam("tagName") String tagName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your url to

```
/registration/getTags/{blahblah}
```

and in controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags/{blahBlah}")
public @ResponseBody List<Tag> getTags(@PathVariable String blahBlah) {
    String tagName="";
    return simulateSearchResult(tagName);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting this is related to the view resolver configuration, you are using

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver
```

You only have one view resolver which returns jsp pages. And in your method you are trying to return a List object which I believe you want to be serialized as JSON in http body.

To return a json response you can try to use @JSONView

[Spring @JsonView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-jsonview)

and add another viewResolver like org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView on the xml config, such as illustrated by this blog

[multiple view resolvers](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You have servlet url mapping at /registration/*

In class you have mapping at /registration

In method you have mapping at /getTags

So, your url is `/registration/registration/getTags?name=blahblah`